# How to replace 2 values before and 2 values after zeros with zero

Tags: r

I am trying to interpolate missing data from a time-series.  The missing data are zeros, but the problem is that the values just before and after the missing data are also invalid.  So I want to interpolate from the value 3 places before a zero to the value 3 places after the last zero in a sequence of zeros.

Here is the `R` code I'm using:

```
library(zoo)
x<- c(90,91,67,45,0,0,0,23,54,94,95)
fixed_x <- data.frame(fixed_pupil=na.approx(replace(pupil,pupil==0,NA)))
```

In this example I want to interpolate from 91 to 94.

My guess is that the easiest way to do this would be to replace the 2 values before and after a sequence of zeros with zeros, but I'm not sure how to do that either.

Comment: For clarification, are the zeros always sequential? Or they may appear in any position?

Comment: I suppose there might be some instance when there is only 1 zero, but for the most part there are several sequences of zeros scattered throughout the time-series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will replace the two values before and after.

```
x <- c(90,91,67,45,0,0,0,23,54,94,95)
zeros <- which(x == 0)
for ( i in zeros ) {
    if ( i - 2 > 0 ) {
        x[c(i-2, i-1)] <- 0
        x[c(i+2, i+1)] <- 0
    }
}
> x
 [1] 90 91  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 94 95
```

As far as interpolating goes more data would be needed, but `ts()` has options for dealing with missing values. You may want to replace with `NA` in that case.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  This worked.  I checked out ts().  My time-series are indeed longer than the example, so I guess `na.kalman` might be a better option than interpolation.